# VBA Receiving ByRef Argument Type Mismatch on Some Items (but not others) when using LastSaved Function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a script that will list the last time/date that each six input templates was last saved.  The first 4 seem to be working fine, but when I get to the 5th & 6th (TemplateWB1 & TemplateWB2), I get the following error:
"Compile Error: ByRef Argument Type Mismatch"

I can't figure out why some of these are working, but not others..?  I've checked and rechecked the filepaths several times and they're correct.

```
Sub RefreshSaveDateTimes()
    Dim DateWBpath As String
    Dim DistWBpath As String
    Dim prdWBpath As String
    Dim sparkUPCitemWBpath As String
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim menuMenuWS As Worksheet
    Dim TemplateWB1, TemplateWB2 As String

    Set menuMenuWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu")

    DateWBpath = "P:\CPW Planning Tool\DataSources\DateTable.xlsx"
    DistWBpath = "P:\CPW Planning Tool\Input Templates\Confections\Confections Distribution Inputs.xlsm"
    prdWBpath = "P:\CPW Planning Tool\Input Templates\Confections\Confections PRD Inputs.xlsm"
    sparkUPCitemWBpath = "P:\CPW Planning Tool\Input Templates\Confections\Confections Spark UPC Item Table.xlsx"
    TemplateWB1 = "P:\CPW Planning Tool\Input Templates\Confections\Forecast Template 1 - Confy.xlsm"
    TemplateWB2 = "P:\CPW Planning Tool\Input Templates\Confections\Forecast Template 2 - Confy.xlsm"

    myDate = LastSaved(DateWBpath)
        menuMenuWS.Cells(2, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = myDate

    myDate = LastSaved(sparkUPCitemWBpath)
        menuMenuWS.Cells(3, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = myDate

    myDate = LastSaved(prdWBpath)
        menuMenuWS.Cells(4, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = myDate

    myDate = LastSaved(DistWBpath)
        menuMenuWS.Cells(5, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = myDate

    myDate = LastSaved(TemplateWB1)
        menuMenuWS.Cells(6, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = myDate

    myDate = LastSaved(TemplateWB2)
        menuMenuWS.Cells(7, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = myDate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because when you write this:

```
Dim TemplateWB1, TemplateWB2 As String
```

`TemplateWB1` is actually declared as a `Variant`, not a `String`. You have to specify the type for each variable:

```
Dim TemplateWB1 As String, TemplateWB2 As String
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rory!  May I ask how (or if) this scenario differs from the example below:?

Comment: Dim i, j, k as long --- won't that delcare all three as long?

Comment: No - `i` and `j` would be `Variant` and only `k` would be `Long`

Comment: Wow - I never knew this.  Well, thank you very much for your help.  I guess I've got quite a bit of code to edit now ;)